# RecyclerView with dynamic cell size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some words, and i want to show them in a recyclerview.

Every row, should have as words as to fit screen width.

e.x. if i have the words { word1, word22222222222222,word3,word4,word5},
i m expecting to see this:

```
word1| word22222222222222
word3|word4|word5
```

or maybe this, in a smaller screen

```
word1|
word22222222222222
word3|word4
word5
```

So my final result, i would like to be something like that

[image]

As now, i have created a recycler view, and i show 4 words in every row, but this is not dynamic as i m expecting to be.

```
mUserRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

How can i achive the expecting result?
I hope my questions is understandable!

Comment: You could try flexbox layoutmanager https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this library

https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager

Using that, u create a custom LayoutManager that works like a charm.

Thanks